# Is there a way to embed a facebook video and have sound start on play on non mobile devices?

Tags: html, facebook, video, embed

This may sound simple but I'm just trying to embed a facebook video (preferrably via iframe but can use SDK method) and have it so when the visitor hits play the video plays with sound. Every video I've played on laptops the video is muted (tried chromebook and Windows computer, various browsers, none has sound unless visitor unmutes it).

However if I play on a iphone the sound plays as one would expect.

I've tried both the SDK and Iframe method and don't know how to get the sound on when someone hits play.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8vgoqf2k/

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPretty52Official%2Fvideos%2Fvb.217293018312810%2F468824230316244%2F&width=500&show_text=false&appId=115391488481724&height=500" width="500" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

On other platforms youtube, soundcloud, etc, the default behavior is for sound to be on when someone hits play. But not facebook (unless it's a phone).

Answer (score 0):

Add `&mute=0` to the iframe url.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPretty52Official%2Fvideos%2Fvb.217293018312810%2F468824230316244%2F&width=500&mute=0&show_text=false&appId=115391488481724&height=500" width="500" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```